# Prove that matrices have equal rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $P$ and $Q$ are $n \times n$ matrices of real numbers such that

1. $P^2=P$ and
2. $Q^2=Q$ and
3. $I-P-Q$ is invertible where $I$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix,

Show that $P$ and $Q$ have the same rank.

If $P$ is non-singular, then it can be shown that $P=Q=I$, so they have same rank. But I can't prove it when $P$ is singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** If $A$ is an invertible matrix, then $\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(XA)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(Y)=\operatorname{rank}(AY)$ for all square matrices $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thank you, I can solve it using this property. But I still don't get the intuition behind it. Can you please explain why rank(X)=rank(XA) ?

Comment: @Rajarshi If $A$ is invertible, one can perform appropriate elementary column operations to transform $A$ into $I$ and hence also transform $XA$ into $X$. Since elementary row operations preserve rank, the rank of $X$ is equal to the rank of $A$.

Comment: Alternatively, as $A$ is invertible, for any vector $v$, we have $v^TX=0$ iff $v^TXA=0$. Therefore $X$ and $XA$ have identical row ranks. To illustrate, suppose the row rank of $X$ is 2 and first two rows of $X$ are linearly independent. Then $v^TX\ne0$ for every nonzero row vector $v^T$ of the form $(c_1,c_2,0,\ldots,0)$. Hence $v^TXA\ne0$ for all such vectors $v$. In other words, the first two rows of $XA$ are linearly indepedent. Therefore the $rank(XA)\ge rank(A)$. Argue in the reverse direction, we get $rank(A)\ge rank(XA)$. So $X$ and $XA$ have equal ranks.